# Make Fix View to All Monitor Resolution

Tags: html, css, resolution, media-queries

I make an application in which i use `div` tag but one problem is that in other or big resolution monitor shows different view on that screen and some other monitor shows another view of my Website. so how can i fix the view for all the monitor resolution. please help me.

Thanks in advance.
Mitesh

Answer (score 1):

`@media` rules help you
[demonstraion site:](http://mediaqueri.es/)
[image]

[Smart presentation](http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrolldeck.js/decks/responsive/) about Responive Web Design using this tech rule

### [link to specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

> A media query consists of a media type and zero or more expressions that check for the conditions of particular media features. Among the media features that can be used in media queries are ‘width’, ‘height’, and ‘color’. By using media queries, presentations can be tailored to a specific range of output devices without changing the content itself.

And also two articles from http://css-tricks.com/:

- [CSS Media Queries & Using Available Space](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)
- [Media Queries for Standard Devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)